# SQL - Where clause and distinct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to perform a SQL query with PDO, that will select data from two different tables, and match them together:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    select a.token, b.token, b.username, COUNT(DISTINCT a.token) adcount, COUNT(DISTINCT b.username WHERE a.token=b.token) clickcount
    from advertisements a, advertisement_clicks b
    where a.status='2' AND (a.clicks_left > 0 OR a.fixed ='1')
    AND b.token=a.token
    ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userdata["id"]); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $s1=$stmt->fetch();
```

So, above SQL doesn't work. I am trying to select ***amount*** of records where `a.token` matches `b.token` as `clickcount`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
a.token, b.token, b.username, COUNT(DISTINCT a.token) adcount, 
COUNT(DISTINCT b.username) clickcount
from advertisements a 
JOIN advertisement_clicks b ON b.token=a.token
where a.status='2' AND (a.clicks_left > 0 OR a.fixed ='1')
```

You are already `join`ing the tables. You need not use a `where` clause in `count`.

Comment: probably need a `group by`?

Comment: What does the group by do?

Comment: because you are using `count` which is an aggregate function, you need to include a `group by` on all the other columns. However, MySQL isn't strict about that.

Comment: When the group by is added, all I get is "1" on all results. If I remove it, I get 12 which is the correct amount.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that select amount of records where `a.token` matches `b.token` as `clickcount`:

```
SELECT a.token, b.token, COUNT(a.token) clickcount
    FROM advertisements a
    JOIN advertisement_clicks b
    ON b.token=a.token
    WHERE a.status='2' AND (a.clicks_left > 0 OR a.fixed ='1')
    GROUP BY a.token;
```

Comment: Try to avoid implicit joins (having two tables in the from clause) is a deprecated syntax, and it's recommended to switch to the modern, explicit, `JOIN` syntax:

Comment: Yes. You still have some issue with the group by .... need to include both  `group by a.token, b.token`